# Axios NTLM doesn't work on POST (but work with GET)

Tags: reactjs, post, iis, axios, http-status-code-401

I need to auto login on my React App. To do this, I use NTLM authentication. Both , API (php coded) and React App are on an IIS server.
I use axios for API calls. When I do GET request, all is right, crendentials are successfully sent (but I must disable anonymous login on IIS).
When I use POST query, it fails with 401 error.

I tried several headers but nothing works. That's why I need help.
[Image : Nothing weird in headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSytc.png)

When I do GET, I see cookie sent, not with my post query

```
 axios.post(apiUrl+'deleteUserReportFolder.php', {
            reportFolder: e.target.value,
            id: user.login
        },{
        withCredentials: true,
        credentials: 'include',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': "application/json",
            'Authorization': 'NTLM',
            'WWW-Authenticate': 'NTLM'

        }
        
    })
```

The API Site is sending these HTTP Response Headers:
[Image : IIS API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YV8OS.png)
Thanks for your help. I've seen a lot of posts but nothing worked.

Edit :
I tried by setting my server (API PHP) with anonymous and Windows login, anonymous login cause no logon user, so I must set Windows enabled only.
I tried by removing all headers except "withCredentials" in axios query. I still have 401 error on CORS Pre Flight.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666651
Look at the reply to this question, and you have similar questions

Comment: This solution doesn't apply here, I don't have password. I don't use Basic authentication, I use NTLM (I want to use windows login).

Comment: You can try to use failed request tracking to view detailed error information.

Comment: @samwu I see same headers as Chrome. No authorization Line. I see "Authentication : NOT AVAILABLE"

Comment: This should be a cors issue, you can refer to this answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/43881141/13336642](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43881141/13336642).

Answer (score 0):

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

Check this code，May be it's helpful!

Comment: Good idea but how can I see the result ? The server send 401 before accessing php script.